# AS3 Load Class of External Library

Tags: class, actionscript-3

Can I import classes on external library without load it? I would like to split my SWF and put only the classes into other referencing SWF since it contains a lot of mp3 file and caused so hard to run. Then I need only the classes inside

Thanks

Comment: You can put your MP3 files into a secondary SWF file and give each a class, then you can load the secondary SWF file into your primary SWF file, is this what you mean?

Comment: No, I only want load the class.